# Problems with file accessing from different directory

Tags: html

how can i acces `mydomain.com/style.css` from `mydomain.com/a_folder/index.html`, without typing `mydomain.com/style.css`? Accessing `mydomain.com/a_folder/script.js` from `mydomain.com/a_folder/index.html` could be done by using `/script.js`. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [this explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) for relative URLs.

Comment: Use `../` to go up one folder in your file directory. So if your accessing `/style.css` which is in the root directory from `/a_folder/index.html` you would use `../style.css`.

Comment: @Sven , KJEK-Code, Thanks for your comments. That helped me :)